How can I export my Location History now that this data is only stored locally on the phone?
Google has been migrating phones to only store Location History data locally on the phone. Once an account has been transitioned, you can no longer export the data using Google Takeout since it is no longer on Google servers.
How can I export my Location History data after my account as been transitioned?

Go to the settings app, then Location->Location Services->Time Line->Export Timeline Data and pick a folder and filename to export to. Wait a little while and then go check the folder and a new JSON file with your complete location history should be there.
Credit to vijaykes for finding this (I would have never found this new option on my own)...
https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/comments/1chlsst/export_google_maps_timeline_data_on_android/la6n0k2/

The answer provided by @bigjosh only works on a small percentage of Android devices, AFAIK. For example on my OnePlus 10 there is no Timeline concept anywhere in the settings, so I have no means of exporting my timeline data now that it's locked away on the phone itself.

Worked on Samsung S21 Ultra/One UI 6.1

Does not work on Google Pixel.

@user Does work on my several google pixels. Has your account been migrated to local location history storage? When you say it does not work, does that mean that you do not have this option, or that you do have this option but when you pick it then you do not get the expected output? If so, do you get an error or just nothing happens? Keep in mind that it takes a while after you execute the menu pick before the generated file shows up.

The option isn't there. My phone has updated and I had the on boarding process for on device location history. No option in the settings menu though. Thanks.

 - it's still available, or at least for me.

Check the file that actually gets exported by Google takeout. For me, the file was empty.

This will probably go away in May next year when they remove web access to your timeline.
